# Passing hashed ssh password in a script

Tags: linux, bash

I am attempting to make a script to log into a server via ssh I can not use keys in this project. So i am trying to pass a hashed password but I am not having any luck .. here is what I have. Any help would be great.

```
!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh nix@server
expect "password:"
send "echo "6YepVNFkMm1YO/WwA+mZEYZrhfVStH4+01fHTCf/La0=" | \
  openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass env:passwd"
interact
```

Here is the return I get:

```
nix's password: extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"send "echo "6YepVNFkMm1YO/WwA+mZEYZrhfVStH4+01fHTCf/La0=" | \
  openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass env:passwd"
interact
"
```

Comment: So ... what part of this is **[tag:bash]**, and why not just use SSH keys?

Comment: Cant use ssh keys in our environment boss gets crazy

Comment: Time to find a new boss then. The authors of OpenSSH have more experience at this than your boss, and storing your password in a reversible hash is just stupid. Please tell him I said so.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution**:

```
!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh nix@localhost
expect "password:"
send "echo '6YepVNFkMm1YO/WwA+mZEYZrhfVStH4+01fHTCf/La0=' | \
  openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass env:passwd"
interact
```

I replaced those double quotes with single quotes ie `"send "echo "6YepVNFkMm1YO/WwA+mZEYZrhfVStH4+01fHTCf/La0="` to `"echo '6YepVNFkMm1YO/WwA+mZEYZrhfVStH4+01fHTCf/La0='`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Care to enlighten the audience as to what you changed, and why it affects the outcome?

Comment: I replaced those double quotes with single quotes ie `"send "echo "6YepVNFkMm1YO/WwA+mZEYZrhfVStH4+01fHTCf/La0="` to `"echo '6YepVNFkMm1YO/WwA+mZEYZrhfVStH4+01fHTCf/La0='`

Comment: Comments are a terrible place for an answer. [Try adding it to your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46029451/edit). The explanation helps the OP and others with similar problems diagnose their own issues should they make the same error again. Educate. Don't just provide free consulting.

Comment: @ghoti  I normally provide explanation in my answer, thank you I will update the answer now.

Comment: I see your explanation, but it doesn't explain *why*. If quotes are important, can you explain how the OP should select different kinds of quotes in a shell script? Some external references wouldn't hurt as well.